# How to reconnect Siri Shortcuts to Dropbox?

Tags: ios, dropbox, shortcuts-app

I have some Shortcuts using Dropbox actions (such as “Get Dropbox File”). Now whenever I try to run them, I get this error:

> An unknown error occurred (invalid_access_token/)

This started to happen after I disconnected all my apps from Dropbox due to some security concerns.

Other apps allow me to easily reconnect to Dropbox, but I couldn’t find a way to do that in Shortcuts.

So how can I reconnect Siri Shortcuts to Dropbox?

(That would also be useful for switching the Dropbox account connect to Siri Shortcuts, by the way).

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, just had to uninstall and reinstall Shortcuts. Then the app asks for a new authorization.